# How to initialize a Firefox profile programmatically

Tags: python, firefox

I want to programmatically initialize a Firefox profile so that all files that are normally created on first run of Firefox are created.

I have tried using [`firefox -CreateProfile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) but it only creates the folder and a `times.json` file. I need the full profile. What I probably need to do is start and close Firefox using Python, but I cannot get Firefox to close.

I am using `subprocess.Popen` so I can retrieve the pid to later close Firefox with `proc.terminate()`, but it is not working. The pid's process is no longer found. Perhaps it has something to do with Firefox multiprocess?

```py
import os
import subprocess
import time

profile_name = 'new_profile'
profile_path = f"C:\\Users\\user\\profiles\\{profile_name}"

os.system(f'firefox -CreateProfile "{profile_name} {profile_path}" -no-remote')
proc = subprocess.Popen(['firefox', '-profile', profile_path, '-no-remote'])
print(f"Pid: proc.pid")
time.sleep(3)
proc.terminate() # Not working
time.sleep(1)
os.system(f"taskkill /F /pid {proc.pid}") # Process not found
```

Running the script and confirming with `taskkill` the process on the original pid is no longer found:

```
Pid: 16472
ERROR: The process "16472" not found.
```

How can I close Firefox using this approach?

Comment: why are you not using selenium?

Comment: Opening Firefox with selenium does not seem to initialize the profile

Comment: Hopefully not too dumb but I ended up killing all firefox.exe processes from `psutil.process_iter` created in the last 10 seconds...